# Why all components in user control of C# Winforms have different size in UI editor and during runtime?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have some c# winforms project. I add there a user control with some standard components to a split container. This user control looks good in UI editor:
[image: How margins looks in editor]

The elements are aligned here in absolute layout. No docking used, and Anchor value is default (top, left).

But during runtime components grow in size:

[image: At runtime it looks worse]

I have checked OnLoad handler and constructor, there is no code which may expand the components.

What makes controls have different size and margins in editor and during runtime? Where should I look?

Comment: There are several forms in project and they have similar problems - components look different in editor and during runtime.

Comment: Play around the properties window, probably the size and anchor properties

Comment: Lack of DPI Awareness syndrome. [How to configure an app to run correctly on a machine with a high DPI setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/how-to-configure-an-app-to-run-correctly-on-a-machine-with-a-high-dpi-setting-e?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved desired result by setting AutoScaleMode property for user control and form to None